# Neuralnet package in r with simple structure taking very long time , what is the issue here?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a problem with `neuralnet` function from `neuralnet` package in R. 
I designed a simple structure with 82 feature as input and only 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons and output is 20 class and I left this line which represent `neuralnet` function to run above 4 hours and didn't finish ! 
This is the code :

```
nn=neuralnet(f, data = train, hidden = 10, err.fct = "sse",threshold = 1, 
             learningrate=.05,rep = 1, linear.output = FALSE)
```

Comment: How many epochs was it training? How much training data did you use?

Comment: Training neural networks can take a very long time. Sometimes it can be prohibitively long. As alluded to by @moose the number of observations plays a major role. You can try with a smaller training set (with the same features) and gradually increase the size, to estimate the feasibility of training the NN with the size of your current training set.

Comment: they are 300000 observations

Answer (score 2):

Training of the neural network can be **arbitrary long**, what affects this time?

- Complexity of the network (not a problem here as your network is quite small)
- Size of the training data - even few thousands of samples can take quite a while, furthermore number of features also significantly increase computation time
- Training algorithm and its hyperparameters - in particular for SGD based solutions - too small learning rate (or to big as it causes the oscilation)
- Type of stopping criterion - there are many ways of checking whether to stop training a NN, some more expensive (validation score) than others (amplitude of gradient/number of epochs).

In your particular example your training takes at most 100,000 steps and you use rprop+ learning. Thus the most probable problem is the size of the training data. You can try to set `stepmax` to some much smaller value to see how much time it needs and how good is the model.

In general - **neural networks are hard and slow to train**, you have to deal with it or switch to other models.

Comment: Yes, and SVMs are not better in that sense. Those are the kind of things that textbooks rarely discuss when treating toy models like the "iris" set.

Comment: You should probably add that the speed depends on several other factors, too: (1) Usage of GPU - I had speed-ups of about 90x after using the GPU with Lasagne (2) frameworks - however, I'm not too sure how R ranks here. However, for only 10 hidden neurons it shouldn't take that long, even if you train 100,000 epochs and have about 160,000 training examples

Comment: @moose I don't think there's any non-commercial GPU package for ANNs in R. Lasagne is for Python, isn't it? It's a pity that the CUDA distribution contains PyCUDA but nothing similar for R, at least not yet.

Comment: @I don't know about R, I'm a Python user ;-P. I guess the most interesting alternative might be [Google TensorFlow](http://martin-thoma.com/tensor-flow-quick/) - it is C++/Python, but if one wants to use neural networks, one should use the GPU.

Comment: first thanks for all of you 
+ i want to know what is the suitable range for stepmax parameter 
and also How to parallelize process

Answer (score 1):

You can easily predict the computation time and complexity of your code before running it on the full data with the `GuessCompx` package.

Create fake data with the same characteristics as yours, and 20-class Y vector and a wrapper function:

```
train = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(300000*82, 3), ncol=82))
train['Y'] = as.character(round(runif(300000, 1,20)))
nn_test = function(data) {
  nn=neuralnet(formula=Y~., data=data, hidden = 10, err.fct = "sse",threshold = 1, 
            learningrate=.05,rep = 1, linear.output = FALSE)
}
```

And then do the audit:

```
library(GuessCompx) # get it by running: install.packages("GuessCompx")
library(neuralnet)
CompEst(train, nn_test)
#### $`TIME COMPLEXITY RESULTS`$best.model
#### [1] "NLOGN"
#### $`TIME COMPLEXITY RESULTS`$computation.time.on.full.dataset
#### [1] "1M 4.86S"
#### $`MEMORY COMPLEXITY RESULTS`$best.model
#### [1] "LINEAR"
#### $`MEMORY COMPLEXITY RESULTS`$memory.usage.on.full.dataset
#### [1] "55535 Mb"
#### $`MEMORY COMPLEXITY RESULTS`$system.memory.limit
#### [1] "16282 Mb"
```

See that the computation time is not a problem, but the memory usage and limitations might be impacting your computer, causing the long delay? The only `nn` output object takes more than 4Gb to be stored!